# module object has no attribute 'DescriptorExtractor_create()'

Tags: sift, surf, opencv3.1

I installed opencv3.1.0 with opencv_contrib correctly installed but I am getting the error no module 'DescriptorExtractor_create()' and everything is fine. Suggestions??? :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenCV 3.x, SIFT and SURF have been removed because they are patented algorithms and as such are not installed by default. However they are available in the 'opencv_contrib' package which is not installed by default with the normal OpenCV installation. You need to install them manually. Consider [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/) for details regarding the same.
Assuming you did this correctly, you need to use commands like `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` instead of `DescriptorExtractor_create()`