# How to intiate BRIEF Extractor in OpenCV_2

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to intialise BRIEF Extractor but following error is coming up:

> `module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'DescriptorExtractor_create'`

```
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector()

brief = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("BRIEF")

kp_1 = fast.detect(first, None)
kp_2 = fast.detect(second, None)

kp_1, desc_1 = brief.detect(first, kp_1)
kp_2, desc_2 = brief.detect(second, kp_2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326747/module-object-has-no-attribute-descriptorextractor-create

Comment: I am trying to use BRIEF and in opencv2.4